# Can we have a 'Direct Debit' tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I have asked a question about direct debits today and noticed that there is no `direct debit` tag.

With [73% of bills](http://www.business-money.com/announcements/automated-payments-at-all-time-high-as-bacs-breaks-six-billion-barrier) payed by direct debit in the UK I think it would be a useful tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added it to your question.